# Docking tables on top of another and viewing both the tables simultaneously in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dockable-window

How to dock attribute table in QGIS such that both tables can be docked horizontally and viewed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This option exists in QGIS 3.14 - [Open attribute tables as tabs](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-open-attribute-tables-as-tabs). You can open many attribute tables and they will be organized in tabs. Then, you can click on each tab to view the contents of each attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Did you use any keyboard shortcuts to open the attribute table for both layers?

Comment: @Taras `F6` is the shortcut for opening attribute tables in QGIS.